# Can user and image companies be set on segment.io / june.so?

Tags: segment-io

I am sending data from my users and companies to segment.io and from there to june.so. In june.so, users and companies have an image, but they seem to be auto assigned for each user/company. I want to change those default images and set a different one for each user or company.

I am going through the documentation and found no reference to this feature. Is this something impossible right now with the current features of segment.io and june.so?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Much like you, I could find no mention of this in the documentation. I would guess that maybe you could set the image using a trait for a user or a group, but it's simply not documented.

The Segment docs suggest that for any issues about the June destination you can contact June support. There is an [email address linked on this page for support](https://segment.com/docs/connections/destinations/catalog/june/#group), I recommend you ask them. And if you find out, come back and answer this question yourself!